# jQuery - different behaviour of before() and after()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sortable list (not jQuery UI sortable, just by a simple click on buttons).
Sorting to the right via `after()` works just fine, but sorting to the left with `before()` does not work.

First of all the code:

*Html*

**PhotoList:**

```
<ul class="PhotoList">
   <li>
       <div class="ThumbWrapper">
           <img src="images/img_testphoto.jpg" />
       </div>
   </li>
   [...more Elements...]
</ul>
```

**Selectable List:**

(positioned absolutely over the photos)

```
<ul class="SelectablePolaroids">
  <li>
    <div class="Selectable">
        <div class="Tools">
            <div class="ArrowLeft Tool">
            </div>
            <div class="Delete Tool">
            </div>
            <div class="ArrowRight Tool">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  [...more Elements...]
</ul>
```

*JS*

**Bind functions**

```
jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids .Selectable .ArrowLeft').live('click', function(){sortPolaroid(jQuery(this),0)});
jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids .Selectable .ArrowRight').live('click', function(){sortPolaroid(jQuery(this),1)});
```

**Function**

```
function sortPolaroid(elm, right)
{
    var selectitem = elm.parents('li');
    var index = jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids').children().index(selectitem);
    var photo = jQuery('.PhotoList').children().eq(index);
    selectitem.remove();
    photo.remove();
    if(right)
    {
        jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids').children().eq(index).after(selectitem);
        jQuery('.PhotoList').children().eq(index).after(photo);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(index);
        jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids').children().eq(index).before(selectitem);
        jQuery('.PhotoList').children().eq(index).before(photo);
    }
 }
```

If `right` is true or `.ArrowRight` was clicked, it works just as expected. The item is removed and inserted one position further to the right.
As you can see I logged `index` to check if the else statement is executed at all and whether the index is correct. And yeah the else statement is executed and the index is correct as well. Is `before()` working in another way than `after()` or am I just blind to another mistake?

**EDIT:**

I have also logged the index after `before()`.

```
//...
else {
   console.log(index);
   jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids').children().eq(index).before(selectitem);
   console.log(jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids').children().index(selectitem));
   jQuery('.PhotoList').children().eq(index).before(photo);
}
```

And it stays the same, nothing changes at all... but it was remove, which means it is inserted at exactly the same position, therfore it works if I am doing the following - **my Solution**:

```
//...
else {
    jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids').children().eq(index-1).before(selectitem);
    jQuery('.PhotoList').children().eq(index-1).before(photo);
}
```

But I don't really know why... the new element should be at the index, and before should insert it before index...
If someone knows please answer I will gladly accept an answer :-)

...

Okay, figured it out by myself and answered, sorry about the ruckus, but maybe some other people don't know as well and are thinking in the same way as me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the element the next and not the previous element gets the index, so it will be inserted into the same position.
It works with `after()` because the element getting the new index is in the "right direction", therefore it works with the following:

```
//...
else
{
    jQuery('.SelectablePolaroids').children().eq(index-1).before(selectitem);
    jQuery('.PhotoList').children().eq(index-1).before(photo);
}
```

Just a logical mistake... solved after appropiate thinking :-)

Answer (score 1):

`photo.remove();` actually removes the dom element from the tree so I think there is mismatching  of indexes. Try using before/after without removing, that just moves the element.

Comment: Thats not the matter, after removing the next element has the former index of the selectitem, therefore im inserting it with after() and before() - the number is stored inside index. Also after() works just fine as I described.... but I tried and actually the elements are being removed at execution, probably because no new DOM element is created and it cannot be inserted after itself.

Comment: But I think my logic and procedure is right there... it has to be removed and inserted after the new element at that index.... and it works with after() at least - but I really appreciate your help :-)

Comment: I have edited my question it works now, sorry bout the ruckus - but I am not yet sure why it works, so you might have a clue? ;-)